# Panel in angular material design

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

[image: Image for design]

I want to create a panel like above using angular 6 material design.

Use the below code

```
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <h3>{{ pageTitle }}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="form.ngSubmit.emit()">Save</button>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button type="reset" mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="progress"></mat-progress-bar>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <mat-card-content>

            <mat-form-field>
<input matInput placeholder="Name [(ngModel)]="vehicleMakeViewModel.name" name="name" required #name="ngModel"></mat-form-field>
        </mat-card-content>

    </mat-card>
```

The above code produce the below template. The title and buttons are not properly align to the template.

[image: template]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but it could be that you have not imported the styles for angular material (or that you have a different style, not the default one).
Try adding this to your styles.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

info here 
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

also for info on themes:
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the OP has in fact imported the styles: the button's colour/color isn't broken.

Comment: apparently there are more styles you can try. For instance: 
deeppurple-amber.css

indigo-pink.css

pink-bluegrey.css

purple-green.css

Comment: Yup, that's from the documentation.

Comment: The css are imported. Since cards and buttons have proper design. Just the template is not working properly. Since all the tags are working fine so css is imported.